# Call listview selected item click, Using Android menu item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-menu

In my android application I have a listview with set of records. I have implemented the OnItemClickListener and set it to the listview. So when user click any listview Item it redirects to next activity and do the stuff I need.

The problem is, I have to implement the same functionality to be performed using android Menu.(When click menu button). When click menu button it displays a menu item, to perform Listviews focused  item to call click event. Simply when click menu item it should perform the the focused listview item click, as when we normally click the listview item.

Have no idea of how to call click event

Can anyone guide me how to do this please....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html.

Comment: Yes Joru, I refered this and my other menu items works fine. The thing I need to know is how to perform the listviews selected item click, when User click the menu item.

Comment: As I have Implemented and set OnItemClickListener to the listview can go to listview and perform the task normally. I need to know like that, how can we call the selected row to perform click event that need to done when click menu item